# Is creating REST subresources to get the last or first element of a list bad practice?

Tags: web-services, rest

Let's say I have built a REST service for making notes that looks something like this:

```java
GET    /notes/     // gives me all notes
GET    /notes/{id} // gives the note with the identified by {id}
POST   /notes/     // creates note
PUT    /notes/{id} // updates note identified by {id}
DELETE /notes/{id} // delete note
```

now I want to create subresources that allows me to get/update/delete the first or last note.

```java
GET    /notes/first // get first note added
PUT    /notes/last  // updates last note added
DELETE /notes/first // delete first note
```

Does this go against the principles of REST?

Thank you in advance :)

**EDIT:**

PS: In this example i expect the ID to be always a number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my humble opinion this is perfectly legal and desirable. I especially like the semantics of `DELETE /notes/first`, but also consider `POST /notes/first` - *put a new note before the first one*.

In your case `first` and `last` are some sort of special magic identifiers or placeholders. On the other hand what are the alternatives?

Comment: Hi Tomasz, thank you for your answer. I like your POST /notes/first consideration, allows it to use the service in a stack like fashion.
Regarding that what would be the best way to move a certain note to first position?

Comment: @Zounadire: good question! My idea is `POST /notes/42/move` or a destructive pair of `DELETE` and `POST /notes/first` :-(

Comment: Hmmm... Ok, but this of course only works if there is an additional field to track the positions in the list, since I want to keep the id the same so that a certain note is always reachable under the same url.

That's why I see a problem with the second approach in cases where the server is responsible for generating the ids: in this case you can't guarantee that the note will have the same id after reposting the note.

Comment: @Zounadire: yes, also if note has some relationships you must be sure to preserve them when deleting and recreating. That's why it's a poor idea. So another shot: `PUT /notes/42/moveToFirst` - I changed `POST` to `PUT` - this method is idempotent.

Comment: Do you see any problems when swapping the positions of two elements?
For example: `PUT /notes/42/swap/24` or `PUT /notes/last/swap/first`

Comment: @Zounadire: well, it is really a matter of preference, looks fine to me (but it should be `POST` in this case). I also though about `/notes/swap/first/last`, but your URI pattern looks better (?)

Comment: I might be about 12 years too late but here's an idea. Assume you could post a new object or a link to an existing one.  With POST /notes/first?type=link you could post a link to GET /notes/{id} so that the target note is now linked from the first position and therefore effectively moved from its original position.